# Copy Row If Cell Range Are Not Blank

Tags: excel, vba

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I have an Excel (2003) spreadsheet called 'Input' with data in columns B to N. What I would like to be able to do is if there is text in any of the cells in column B, I would like to copy the row but only columns 'B' 'I' and 'N' and paste them into my second spreadsheet called 'Output' at cell ref B2.

If at all possible, once the information has been pasted, I'd like to add the word 'Scheduled site' in column 'E' on the 'Output' sheet if the cells in column 'B' have text in them.

I've been doing this manually, and it takes quite some time to do.

I just wondered whether someone may be able to show me please how I can automate this.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you any experience with macros?

Comment: Hi, apologies if my post caused offence. I'm currently using a formula to show the wording 'Scheduled Site'. It works but, it's not quite a slick as I would like. In terms of recording the macro, then yes I've recorded one which copies and pastes between the sheets, but I'm unable to get the script to look for non blank cells, and it's that where I've come unstuck. I'm always very concerned about leaving lengthy posts, hence why I didn't include all of this, but I completely understand what you're saying. I'll consider this as a learning point. Kind regards.

Comment: I thought your question was understandable as is. You can use SpeciallCells (with or without VBA) to quickly identify non-blanks, although for code SpecialCells it needs to cater for constants, formulae, or both constants + formulae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your data looks like below, and you text entries are not formulae, then this approach will be very fast as it exploits SpecialCells to avoid looping rows

```
Sub MoveEM2()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Set ws1 = Sheets("Input")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Output")
On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = ws1.Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlConstants)
On Error GoTo 0
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set rng2 = ws2.[b2]
rng1.Copy rng2
'copy column I to Output C2
rng1.Offset(0, 7).Copy rng2.Offset(0, 1)
'copy column N to Output d2
rng1.Offset(0, 12).Copy rng2.Offset(0, 2)
rng2.Offset(0, 3).Resize(rng1.Cells.Count, 1) = "Scheduled Site"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

[updated for further query]

```
Sub MoveEM()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Input")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Output")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.[b4], ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rng2 = ws2.[b2]
    rng1.Copy
    rng2.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    'copy column I to Output C2
    rng1.Offset(0, 7).Copy
    rng2.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    'copy column N to Output d2
    rng1.Offset(0, 12).Copy
    rng2.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    rng2.Offset(0, 3).Resize(rng1.Cells.Count, 1) = "Scheduled Site"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this, it's really great. Could you tell me please where I would need to change the code so it's starting point of where it will start to copy from is cell 'B4' rather than column 'B'. Sorry my mistake. Kind regards

Comment: change `Set rng1 = ws1.Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlConstants)
`   to `Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.[b4], ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlConstants)`

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this. I'm really very sorry to be a complete pain. But is there a way to get the code to paste special the figures rather than paste. I recorded this as a macro and the recorded code includes the 'pastspecial' command, but I can't find the 'paste' command in your code to change. Kind regards

Comment: Hi, what did you want to accomplish with the paste special. Avoid copying formats?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to use paste special because two of the columns from the 'Input' sheet contain formulae. I don't need to copy the formulae only the values. As it stands at the moment when I copy the applicable columns across they are marked with #Value! Many thanks

Comment: I have posted a second code routine incorporating both changes. cheers

Comment: Hi, that's absolutley brilliant. Many thanks for all your time and trouble. I really appreciate it. Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

I was looking to do the same in a Google Docs spreadsheet so macros were out, I managed to do it with some IFs and VLOOKUPs. It seems a bit convoluted, maybe someone has a more effective way to do this, but this should work without macros:

To the left of the input, I created a column starting with 0 and incrementing every time column B has data in it:

```
A1=0
A2=IF(ISBLANK(B2),A1,A1+1)
A3=IF(ISBLANK(B3),A2,A2+1)
...
```

so the first sheet looks like this:

```
0    
1    data1
1
2    data2
3    data3
3    
3
4    data4
```

Then on the output sheet, have a column with simply incrementing values and do a vlookup for the first row containing that number:

```
A1=1
A2=2
...
```

and

```
B1=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)
B2=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)
...
```

So the second sheet looks like this:

```
1    data1
2    data2
3    data3
4    data4
```

Do another vlookup for any other columns you want to transfer from the first sheet, then hide the columns with the numbers in them.

Answer (score 1):

IRHM,

Just in case, you know how to handle this here is an example. Remember, everyone does things differently, so this is probably not the fastest or most elegant way.

```
Sub MoveData()
    Sheets("Output").Select
    'Select the input sheet
    OutputRowCounter = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1 
     'find the last used row in column A of the output sheet
    Sheets("Input").Select 'Select the input sheet
    InputMaxRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row 'find the last used row in column A of the input sheet

    For rowLoop = 2 To InputMaxRow 'loop through the file and copy data from columns B-N to output A-M
        If Cells(rowLoop, 2).Value <> "" Then 'if the current cell (changing row and fixed column B) has any data...
            For ColLoop = 2 To 14 'Loop through columns B-N
                Worksheets("Output").Cells(OutputRowCounter, ColLoop - 1).Value = Cells(rowLoop, ColLoop).Value 'copy selected data
           Next ColLoop 'go to next column
             OutputRowCounter = OutputRowCounter + 1 'store the next row in the output sheet
        End If
    Next rowLoop
End Sub
```

Comment: Robert some minor points, (1) the question only wanted to copy B, I and N. (2) Range("A65536") assumes xl2003. Use `Cells(Rows.Count,"A")` instead to find the bottom cell regardless of version (3) Lastly pls in future look to provide full answers, not partial code blocks. :)

Comment: Thank you Brettdj for your feedback.

Comment: BrettDJ, how did you correct the code layout?. I looked for a "Code Start" & "Code End" tag, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Robert, there aren't code start and end tags. You can use spaces to force your code into place if the default menu option hasn't worked, plus you can preview your post in the pane below where you are typing

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it.  This puts your data in an array and then looks through the array for rows that have values in Column B.  This should run a little faster than going through your column/sheet cell by cell, but the difference will probably be noticeable only for large data sets.

```
Sub summarize()

Dim sIn As Worksheet, sOut As Worksheet, rIn As Range, rOut As Range
Dim inputdata() As Variant
Dim tmpArr(1 To 3) As Variant
Dim i As Long, outcount As Long

Set sIn = Sheets("Input")
Set sOut = Sheets("Output")
Set rIn = sIn.UsedRange
Set rOut = sOut.Range("B2:D2")

'Loads input data into an array for fast processing.
inputdata = rIn.Value
outcount = 0

'Reads data from inputdata Array and prints selected values from columns B, I, and N on Output sheet row by row.
For i = 1 To UBound(inputdata, 1)
    If inputdata(i, 1) <> "" Then
        outcount = outcount + 1
        tmpArr(1) = inputdata(i, 1)
        tmpArr(2) = inputdata(i, 8)
        tmpArr(3) = inputdata(i, 13)
        rOut.Offset(outcount - 1, 0).Value = tmpArr
        Erase tmpArr
    End If
Next i
Erase inputdata
'Add "Scheduled Site" to Column E of Output data.
If sOut.Range("B2") <> "" Then
    sOut.Range("E2") = "Scheduled Site"
    sOut.Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=sOut.Range("E2", sOut.Range("E2").Offset(outcount - 1, 0))
End If
End Sub
```